# Pythonic way to compare a list of words against a list of sentences and print the matching line

Tags: python

I'm currently cleaning out our database and its becoming very time consuming. The typical

```
for email in emails:
```

loop is in nowhere even close to fast enough.

For instance I am currently comparing a list of 230,000 emails to a 39,000,000 line full records list. It would take hours to match these emails to the records line they belong to and print. Does anyone have any idea how to implement threading into this query to speed it up? and athough this is super fast

```
strings = ("string1", "string2", "string3")
for line in file:
    if any(s in line for s in strings):
        print "yay!"
```

That would never print the matching line, just the needle.

Thank you in Advance

Comment: So you want to print "yay" (or do something meaningful) if any word in the file matches one of the strings (emails)?

Comment: Are you scanning for whole lines or parts of lines in emails from the records list?

Comment: This isn't the fault of the loop, but rather that you have an `O(n*m)` code where both n and m are large values. This will require to at least 9 trillion comparison operations (!). Any language will be slow with the same algorithm. You'd want to convert the problem to an `O(n+m)` problem instead, and slider's answer with using `set` does that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's example solution using threads. This code splits your data in equal chunks and use them as arguments for `compare()` by amount threads that we declare.

```
strings = ("string1", "string2", "string3")
lines = ['some random', 'lines with string3', 'and without it',\
         '1234', 'string2', 'string1',\
         "string1", 'abcd', 'xyz']

def compare(x, thread_idx):
    print('Thread-{} started'.format(thread_idx))
    for line in x:
        if any(s in line for s in strings):
            print("We got one of strings in line: {}".format(line))
    print('Thread-{} finished'.format(thread_idx))
```

Threading part:

```
from threading import Thread

threads = []
threads_amount = 3
chunk_size = len(lines) // threads_amount

for chunk in range(len(lines) // chunk_size):
    threads.append(Thread(target=compare, args=(lines[chunk*chunk_size: (chunk+1)*chunk_size], chunk+1)))
    threads[-1].start()

for i in range(threads_amount):
    threads[i].join()
```

Output:

```
Thread-1 started
Thread-2 started
Thread-3 started
We got one of strings in line: string2
We got one of strings in line: string1
We got one of strings in line: string1
We got one of strings in line: lines with string3
Thread-2 finished
Thread-3 finished
Thread-1 finished
```

Comment: OMG Thank you so much, this is perfect.

Comment: Just want to say thank you one more time, just sorted a 39 million line file against 280,000 unique records in 17 seconds using 1000 threads

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html) to store emails. This makes the the check `if word in emails` *O(1)*. So work done is proportional to the total number of words in your file:

```
emails = {"string1", "string2", "string3"} # this is a set

for line in f:
    if any(word in emails for word in line.split()):
        print("yay!")
```

You original solution is *O(nm)* (for *n* words and *m* emails) as opposed to *O(n)* with the `set`.